# Symfony 4 Recaptcha bundle "public_key" at path "ewz_recaptcha" must be configured

Tags: php, symfony, recaptcha, symfony4

I'm using symfony 4 and recaptcha bundle from https://packagist.org/packages/excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle#v1.5.11, but i don't know why it doesn't work. Below is the error i got. I configured env google recaptcha variables.

> The file "C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\symfony-template\config/packages/ewz_recaptcha.yaml" does not contain valid YAML in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\symfony-template\config/packages/ewz_recaptcha.yaml (which is loaded in resource "C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\symfony-template\config/packages/ewz_recaptcha.yaml").

yaml file:

```
    ewz_recaptcha:
      public_key:  HIDDEN
      private_key:  HIDDEN
      # Not needed as "%kernel.default_locale%" is the default value for the locale key
      locale_key:  %kernel.default_locale%
```

`HIDDEN` equals keys from google, but i covered it here for security reasons.

Comment: Did you create `config/packages/ewz_recaptcha.yaml` file?

Comment: If not, You have to create. and configure the bundle like here https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle

Comment: No, i thought it was automatic process. I createad it now, but still got other error, updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes:

First: You have to create `config/packages/ewz_recaptcha.yaml`

Second: YAML file have to valid format:

```
 ewz_recaptcha:
    public_key:  "here is your public key (this is just example)" 
    private_key: "here is your private key (this is just example too)
    # Not needed as "%kernel.default_locale%" is the default value for the locale key
    locale_key:  %kernel.default_locale%
```

Comment: Thanks i did it, after creation a yaml file it throw an yaml error caused by no quoutes for value for locale_key.

Comment: Can you help me with last thing? I get this error when trying go to register page:      Neither the property "recaptcha" nor one of the methods "getRecaptcha()", "recaptcha()", "isRecaptcha()", "hasRecaptcha()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\User".

Comment: You must add new field to `App\Entity\User`

Comment: Oh! Is it necessary? I only need it once, when user trying to sign up. What fields have to i add?

Comment: Ok i found what i should add. Thanks for all, if it will work.

Comment: With the string you give, it makes absolutely no difference for YAML to have double quotes around the value for `public_key` or not. And the value for `private_key` has a starting double quote, but no closing double quote, making your snippet to be invalid YAML. It is better if you should describe **in words** what needs to be done in your answer and then give the code as an example.